# How to make a plain ruby object assignable as active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel, acts-as-audited

I have an `Audit` class which is backed by ActiveRecord.

```
class Audit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, polymorphic: true
end
```

I have a `User` class which is a plain ruby object with some ActiveModel functionality included. It's not a database model because my users are actually stored in a different database and served over an API.

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming

  def self.primary_key
    'id'
  end

  def id
    42
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

I'm trying to assign a user to an audit like this:

```
audit = Audit.new
audit.user = User.new
audit.save!
```

From a data perspective, this should work ok. To define a polymorphic association, we need to put values into two columns on the audits table. We can set `audits.user_id` to the value `42` and `audits.user_type` to the string "User".

However, I hit an exception:

```
undefined method `_read_attribute' for #<User:0x007f85faa49520 @attributes={"id"=>42}> (NoMethodError)
active_record/associations/belongs_to_polymorphic_association.rb:13:in `replace_keys'
```

I traced that back to the `ActiveRecord` source and it seems to be defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9f1b5c9b4032d081f5b7d7fe9697ba24e2ae3ff8/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb). Unfortunately, the fact that it's `ActiveRecord` rather than `ActiveModel` means that I can't include that mixin into my class.

I tried defining my own `_read_attribute` method but I go down a rabbit hole of having to redefine more and more ActiveRecord functionality like [AttributeSet](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb) and so on.

I also realise that I can workaround the problem by assigning `Audit#user_type` and `Audit#user_id`. That is unsatisfactory however because, in reality, I would have to fork a gem and edit it to do that.

How can I modify my User class so that I can cleanly assign it to an audit.

P.S. [Here's a sample app](https://gist.github.com/dtuite/161d765b679fb5c908d6) so you can try this yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of hacking deeper and deeper to replicate `ActiveRecord` functionality, you may want to consider actually inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` instead of including `ActiveModel`. Your only constraint is that you don't have a table. There's a gem for that:

[activerecord-tableless](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless)

This class works with your sample app:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'activerecord-tableless'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table

  # required so ActiveRecord doesn't try to create a new associated
  # User record with the audit
  def new_record?
    false
  end

  def id
    42
  end
end
```